# How to use glClearTexImage for packed depth/stencil textures?

Tags: c++, opengl

Is it possible to use [glClearTexImage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearTexImage.xhtml) to clear a packed depth/stencil texture in OpenGL? And if so, how?

I'm using a multisample texture with pixel format GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV. Attempting to clear the texture with

```
glClearTexImage(textureId, 0, GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV, GL_FLOAT, nullptr);
```

yields the error

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. <format> must be GL_DEPTH_STENCIL for depth-stencil textures.
```

The fact that depth/stencil textures are considered in this error message lets me believe it should be possible somehow.

If I change the format parameter to GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, I get the error

```
GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Texture type and format combination is not valid.
```

Am I mixing up the parameters? Or did I miss that clearing of packed textures was not within specs? Using a simple GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F instead of the packed format works flawlessly. I also tried creating a texture view with only the depth component and provide its id as first parameter to glClearTexImage, which however yields the same error.

I am testing this in an OpenGL 4.6 context on an Nvidia Titan RTX in Windows 10.

Comment: What format did you use when you created it?

Comment: GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8, i.e. glTextureStorage2DMultisample(textureId, numSamples, GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8, width, height, false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have mixed up the internal format and the data type, which is why I used the wrong parameters. The packed depth/stencil texture can be cleared with

```
glClearTexImage(textureId, 0, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL, GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV, nullptr);
```